# Ubuntu 16.04 issue : Applications does not have own title bars, and undetachable

Tags: 16.04, unity

I am using 16.04.1 LTS.
With the vanilla unity version that comes with the distribution.

Recently, all of a sudden (probably after some update)
The title bar for application windows are no longer visible.
When new application windows appear, they appear merged and attached with the global title bar.

And there is no ways to detach them, or access their menu items.
(with some exceptions like firefox).

Can any one help me here?
I tried using compiz manager to reset the preferences to default.
It does not help.

Thanks in advance.
-Saravanan

Attaching one such issue. (see how the terminal window is attached with the global title bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Now paste the following command in the terminal:

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && setsid unity`

This resets the settings of compiz, the Window Manager of the Unity desktop, to the factory defaults. The 'setsid' command restarts unity in a totally fresh session.

Eventually, you may need to log out and back in before you see results.

Comment: It didn't solve the issue either.

Comment: Perhaps try restarting

Comment: It worked! Should have tried this earlier, the universal fix:)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I updated the question with the info that logging out/in might be needed (don't have Unity anymore, but I thought it was sometimes fixed immediately just with the command).